# How to customize mobile device detector?

Tags: sitecore, 51degrees

I have a customize request from my client in sitecore mobile module.
I want to be on full view site from my mobile on Career page, i am able to do it but any of the link inside career page with having mobile layout in presentation detail is taking that page again to mobile device.
Can we make any customization that maintain the device in cookies so that it keep user on full view site after coming to career page.
Is there any setting we can do in pipeline or session. I just want to be throughout in full view site after coming on career page and no going back to mobile layout. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do exactly that. You'd need to update the rule to detect the various devices (which I'm guessing you already have). You can then create a custom condition to check if cookies have been set for the full site(does not need to be a cookie of course, but that'd be the easiest way).

You can find the existing `Conditions` and `Actions` here in the path `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules`. 
To create custom conditions and actions, please read the [following article on SitecoreInsight.com](http://www.sitecoreinsight.com/custom-rules-and-conditions-in-sitecore-7/)

After creating your custom condition, go into your device item again and update the Rule there to only switch to that device when that cookie has not been set.

**[edit]**
Come to think about it, it might be possible to have your 'go to full site' link appended with a querystring `sc_device={GUID of device}`. I'm not sure what would take precedence here, the 51degrees rules or Sitecore's cookies... Worth a try though :-)

Comment: Thanks Trayek, that's useful but not getting how to actually implement this idea, something is missing from my  end and its not working for me.
Meanwhile in order to make it possible to implement "switch to the normal website version"  button, I've added functionality(based on session-level cookies) for persisted device switching. If you switch to another device using "sc_device=%name of the device%" and add "&persisted=true" parameter, the device will remain switched until you reopen the browser.

Still in dev mode but want to know your way of implementation as you suggested above.