# Not able to switch on mobile site in sitecore after browser close

Tags: cookies, sitecore, sitecore7

I used ?sc_device=default&persisted=true in querystring to keep me on full site(pages with no mobile layout) on mobile device. Disadvantage i am facing right now is that this query string is not letting me switch to mobile device again when i am closing the browser. Its making me to clear cookies which i do not want. Any fix?

Comment: What do you mean by `when i am closing the browser`? Also, how are you trying to get the mobile page back?

Comment: what about ?sc_device=mobile&persisted=true

Comment: apologies for not in brief, actually going thru long chain of this problem [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623240/how-to-customize-mobile-device-detector/29627473#29627473)this to keep website in full desktop site in my mobile.
?sc_device=default&persisted=true create cookie and works well. But  problem is if you want to come back to mobile site, even if you try queystring it will not worked once cookies are created.
Now i want to remove this cookie on browser close event so that user get into mobile site on fresh view and than full site link takes him into desktop mode.